# MS Access API Request

Tags: vba, api

This is my first post here though have been using the great advice/solutions here for years so am very grateful. But this one, I can't find solution for.

I have an MS access front end/back end in use for various office admin tasks and records. Much of the data my office works with on a daily basis is cloud based. However API access is provided with app key and secret key. I have no issues using the API explorer with these keys, but can't get anything through code (VBA). I keep reading it is perfectly possible to do this with VBA which is why I kept trying different solutions, but now need help. (I have replaced URL and keys etc)

```
Dim myObj As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim url, endPoint, params, tickers, appKey, secretKey  As String
url = "theURL.com"
endPoint = "theEndPoint"
params = "id="
tickers = "1"
appKey = "12345678"
secretKey = "12345678"
myObj.Open "GET", url, False
myObj.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
myObj.setRequestHeader "app-key", appKey
myObj.setRequestHeader "secret-key", secretKey
myObj.send
```

This returns "App Key is required." I have tried various solutions including converting keys to Base64, putting the keys within the Open request, sending the keys as part of the send request etc. Always get "App Key is required" when reading response. I know in this code I have't actually requested anything but that returns same message when I do. I just wanted to keep what I posted simple.

Any help at all is greatly appreciated as this would allow great deal of automation for our office.

Thanks

James

Comment: Can you show us a network trace of what happens when you use API Explorer (redacted of  course)? This will help compare a correct request with what you are doing in vba.

Comment: Wild guess, but could it be "api-key" instead of "app-key"?

Comment: Crowcoder, unfortunately not "api-key." I can see the allowed headers in the Explorer and it is "app-key." Having never used a network trace I had to Google and used Netsh on cmd line.  I then opened the ETL file in Event Viewer but not sure what parts are important as each entry is separate. PS Thanks for helping.

Comment: I don't know what API Explorer you are using but if it is a browser tool then just look at the Network tab of the dev tools (F12). Also, if you can make it work with Postman or Fiddler then you will easily be able to see the raw HTTP request.

Comment: Ah Ok, I see it. Any particular section? (General, Response Headers, Request Headers), as it is too big to paste here.

Comment: The Headers tab will probably be good enough for a GET request.

Comment: I have found the issue.  (thanks to your advice on viewing the Network Tab). When converting to base64, the App key matches what explorer receives but the secret key does not. When I put the converted values I can see on network tab on the explorer, it works.

Comment: So I guess the question becomes, is the secret key to be encoded differently and if so, how can I find that out....

Comment: I can't say without knowing more context of the API and how you are obtaining the values for explorer. Are the values for secret key totally different, or do they differ by just ending `=` characters?

Comment: They are completely different. I suppose I could just send the already encoded string (as that works) but my guess is that's not a good idea security wise. Keys are 40 chars and encoded they are 54 chars. The Explorer shows me the encoded keys (joined). The first half matches the converted appKey I send, but the 2nd half does not match the encoded secret key.  Are there any other common encoded types used for keys that this may be?

Comment: Base64 is by far most common. I don't know what you mean by "joined" or first half/second half. All I know about your api is what you have shown in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I mean on the explorer, the key and secret keys show as one long (encoded) string. I can't seem to make that string using base64, but I can make the first half of it using the app key.